# ORACLE - Interpret column value

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I want to calculate a date with INTERVAL.

```
(DATE_LAST_RUN - INTERVAL '1' MONTH) for example.
```

When I do :

```
SELECT sysdate - INTERVAL '1' MONTH  FROM  dual
```

Result:

```
18/08/19
```

This works fine.

But when I use the value from a column it doesn't.

Test :

```
CREATE TABLE test (date_last_run DATE, frequence VARCHAR2(255 CHAR));
INSERT INTO test VALUES (sysdate, ' - INTERVAL ''1'' MONTH');
COMMIT;
```

1st SELECT :

```
SELECT DATE_LAST_RUN + FREQUENCE FROM  test;
```

Error I get :

```
ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
*Action:   Specify a valid number.
```

Dummy SELECT :

```
SELECT DATE_LAST_RUN || FREQUENCE FROM  test;
```

Dummy result :

```
18/09/19 - INTERVAL '1' MONTH
```

My point : Any idea on how to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you aware of [Oracle Dynamic SQL](https://www.guru99.com/dynamic-sql-pl-sql.html) ? I think that may be what you require.

Comment: `SELECT DATE '2019-03-31' - INTERVAL '-1' MONTH FROM DUAL` fails with `ORA-01839: date not valid for month specified` as `2019-02-31` does not exist. If you want to add months then use the `ADD_MONTHS` function.

Comment: Don't use dynamic SQL without appropriate safeguards as your `frequence` column is ripe for performing SQL injection attacks. `INSERT INTO test ( date_last_run, frequence ) VALUES ( sysdate, '- (SELECT 1 FROM hidden_table WHERE secret_key = ''hidden information'')' );`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why use `VARCHAR()` to represent an interval when Oracle already has the built-in `INTERVAL` datatype?

I would handle your use case as follows:

```
-- create a table to store the interval with the proper data type
CREATE TABLE test (date_last_run DATE, frequence INTERVAL YEAR TO MONTH);

-- insert
INSERT INTO test VALUES (sysdate,  INTERVAL '-1' MONTH);

-- now you can select
SELECT DATE_LAST_RUN +  FREQUENCE FROM  test;
```

Yields:

```
| DATE_LAST_RUN+FREQUENCE |
| :---------------------- |
| 18-AUG-19               |
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6e26513975e19f693f58a71dff43e28c)**

Comment: Don't use `INTERVAL YEAR TO MONTH` to add to dates; this does not always work: `INSERT INTO test VALUES ( DATE '2019-03-31', INTERVAL '-1' MONTH )` gives `ORA-01839: date not valid for month specified`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `INTERVAL YEAR TO MONTH` as it will fail when the resulting date does not exist (i.e. `DATE '2019-03-31' - INTERVAL '1' MONTH` will give `ORA-01839: date not valid for month specified`).

Instead, have two columns for the value of the interval and the type of interval and use a `CASE` statement and the `ADD_MONTHS` function:

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test (date_last_run DATE, value NUMBER, frequence VARCHAR2(10) );
INSERT INTO test ( date_last_run, value, frequence )
  SELECT sysdate,           -1, 'MONTH' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2019-03-31', -1, 'MONTH' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2020-02-29', -1, 'YEAR'  FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT t.*,
       CASE frequence
       WHEN 'MONTH' THEN add_months( date_last_run, value )
       WHEN 'YEAR'  THEN add_months( date_last_run, 12 * value )
       END AS updated_date
FROM   test t
```

**Output**:

> ```
> DATE_LAST_RUN | VALUE | FREQUENCE | UPDATED_DATE
> :------------ | ----: | :-------- | :-----------
> 18-SEP-19     |    -1 | MONTH     | 18-AUG-19   
> 31-MAR-19     |    -1 | MONTH     | 28-FEB-19   
> 29-FEB-20     |    -1 | YEAR      | 28-FEB-19
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9879ebc3f53e96caf3a1cb9a59be1488)*

Comment: OK I understand what you meant now when commenting on my answer. +1 this looks like a better solution than mine.

Answer (score 0):

If you do what you are doing, dynamic SQL could help. For example:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> select * from test;

DATE_LAST_RUN       FREQUENCE
------------------- ------------------------------
18.09.2019 10:57:34  - INTERVAL '1' MONTH

SQL> declare
  2    l_str varchar2(200);
  3    l_res date;
  4  begin
  5    select 'select to_date(' || chr(39) || date_last_run  || chr(39)   ||
  6                           ', ''dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'')' || frequence || ' from dual'
  7      into l_str
  8      from test;
  9
 10    execute immediate l_str into l_res;
 11
 12    dbms_output.put_line('result = ' || l_res);
 13  end;
 14  /
result = 18.08.2019 10:57:34

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Don't use `INTERVAL YEAR TO MONTH` to add to dates; this does not always work: `INSERT INTO test VALUES ( DATE '2019-03-31', INTERVAL '-1' MONTH )` gives `ORA-01839: date not valid for month specified`.

Comment: Also this is ripe for SQL injection attacks. `INSERT INTO test VALUES ( SYSDATE, '- (SELECT 1 FROM hidden_table WHERE secret_key = ''hidden information'')' )`

Comment: [DB<>FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=19cec024f6efd474865fbfb44a25fdd2) with an example for an SQL injection attack.

Comment: @MT0, no objection to what you said. I just wanted to show *how* to do such things, i.e. my intention was dynamic SQL (over something that's already stored in a table).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your answers.

I found the NUMTOYMINTERVAL/NUMTODSINTERVAL and TO_YMINTERVAL/TO_DSINTERVAL that can convert my FREQUENCE values if I adapt them a little bit.

Instead of the complete statement, i added a frequence_type field :

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=53c78bd37f0190238ca5010e17448bf3